# Why isn't content script loading after getting compiled?

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension that takes a URL from a queue, opens it in a new window, runs a content script, then repeats. I've begun the task of migrating it to Webpack and Typescript for ease of development, but I've run into the issue of the content script not loading after everything is transpiled.

This extension worked correctly when it wasn't running through webpack and typescript. Once I integrated the pre-existing code with a boilerplate, everything but the content script worked fine.

src/content_script.ts

```js
import extactor from './scripts/extractor';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.extractData) {
    console.log("received data extraction request", request);
    extactor().then(data => {
      sendResponse(data);
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

webpack/webpack.common.js

```
  context: path.join(__dirname, "../"),
  entry: {
    popup: path.join(__dirname, srcDir + "popup.ts"),
    background_script: path.join(__dirname, srcDir + "background_script.ts"),
    content_script: path.join(__dirname, srcDir + "content_script.ts")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../dist/js"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      name: "vendor",
      chunks: "initial"
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

and the manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "tabs", "notifications", "storage", "downloads"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/background_script.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": [
                "js/content_script.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In non-typescript/webpack branch the extension works fine, attempting to run the transpiled code will cause popup.js and background script to work fine, but since content_script.js isn't running, the background page returns

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Comment: I don't know webpack so I suggest looking at the code of the compiled content script (you can do it in devtools, even prettify it there). Hopefully there'll be something obvious.

Comment: IIRC the usual reason is that the produced script is a module so it only defines an `export`, but doesn't actually invoke it.